# jsTree : how to progressively load children (no ajax)

Tags: javascript, jstree

How to load progressively the children of an node, without using ajax, but a private function ?

In the documentation of json_data, it says `json_data.data` can be a function :

> You can also set this to a function - it will be executed in the tree's scope for every node that needs to be loaded, the function will receive two arguments - the node being loaded & a function to call with the data once your processing is done.

But how to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on CheeseWizzz's [post](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/140).

```js
"json_data" : {
    "data" : function(n, b){
        b(custom_function(n));
    },
    "progressive_render" : true
},
```

This is an example of the `custom_function` will have to return a valid json data :

```js
function custom_function(n){
    if (n == -1) // root node
        return ParentNodes();
    else
        var eltID = n.attr('elt');
        return ChildrenOf(eltID);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```